# Как отследить изменение денег игрока в SourceMod?

Tags: разработка-игр, steam

Пишу плагин для CSGO. Можно ли как-то отловить изменение баланса игрока? Пробовал вот так, но оно возвращает баланс ДО изменения. Можно ли как-то получать баланс после изменения?

```php
new Cash = GetEntProp(client, Prop_Send, "m_iAccount");
```